# Apache Pig not using appropriate RecordWriter or OutputCommitter

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, emr, elastic-map-reduce

#### The Problem

I'm using a custom `StoreFunc`, `OutputFormat`, and `OutputCommitter` for use with Pig. The problem that I'm having is that Pig isn't calling some of the methods that I've defined in the `OutputFormat` that return the appropriate `RecordWriter` and `OutputCommitter`. This causes the data to be written somewhere else (I'm honestly not sure where) rather than the intended destination. Pig doesn't throw any errors during the job.

A simple example Pig script:

```
data = LOAD '<url>' USING com.company.CompanyLoader();
STORE data INTO '<other url>' USING com.company.CompanyStorage();
```

Here's what I know:

- Pig calls the `getOutputFormat` method on the `StoreFunc`. So that's good.
- Pig calls `checkOutputSpecs` on the `OutputFormat`. Great.
- Pig **does not call** `getOutputCommitter` nor `getRecordWriter` on the OutputFormat. I'm logging what type of OutputFormat and OutputCommitter Pig is currently using in the `checkOutputSpecs` method, and the results are `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter`. I'm not sure this means that Pig is actually using either of these, since I figure Pig may substitute these with my own `OutputFormat` and `OutputCommitter` after calling the appropriate methods on my `StoreFunc`/`OutputCommitter`.

I'm not explicitly setting an `OutputFormat` nor `OutputCommitter` anywhere in PIG_OPTS. I suspect that Pig is picking up on other `OutputFormat`/other classes from somewhere else, but I'm out of ideas for where to check.

Can anyone lend any insight or further debugging steps in this matter?

#### Example Code

This isn't my actual code, but this demonstrates how I've set things up. I don't modify the configuration while running.

**MyStoreFunc.java**

```
public class MyStoreFunc extends StoreFunc {

    CustomOutputFormat OutputFormat = new CustomOutputFormat();
    private RecordWriter out;

    public OutputFormat getOutputFormat() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("getOutputFormat called.");
        return outputFormat;
    }

    public void prepareToWrite(final RecordWriter writer) throws IOException {
        out = writer;
        LOG.info("Using RecordWriter: " + writer.getClass());

        // other preparation
    }

    public void setStoreLocation(final String location, final Job job) {
        try {
            LOG.info("Output format class is set to: " + job.getOutputFormatClass());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.info("Output foramt class is undefined.");
        }
        LOG.info("Output committer is " + job.getConfiguration().get("mapred.output.committer.class", "undefined"));
        // other preparation
    }

    // other stuff...
}
```

**CustomOutputFormat.java**

```
public class CustomOutputFormat<K, V> extends OutputFormat<K, V> {

    public CustomOutputFormat() {
        LOG.info("CustomOutputFormat created.");
    }

    public void checkOutputSpecs(final JobContext context) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("checkOutputSpecs called.");
        try {
            LOG.info("output format = " + context.getOutputFormatClass());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.info("output format not found.");
        }
        // Check some stuff in configuration
    }

    public OutputCommitter getOutputCommitter(final TaskAttemptContext ctx) {
        LOG.info("getOutputCommitter called.");
        return new CustomOutputCommitter();
    }

    public RecordWriter<K, V> getRecordWriter(final TaskAttemptContext ctx) {
        LOG.info("getRecordWriter called.");
        return new CustomRecordWriter<K, V>();
    }

}
```

#### Example Logs

The log output coming from the custom classes looks like this:

```
2015-06-30 00:08:32,100 [main] INFO    CustomOutputFormat created.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,104 [main] INFO    Output format class is set to: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
2015-06-30 00:08:32,110 [main] INFO    Output committer is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter
2015-06-30 00:08:32,120 [main] INFO    getOutputFormat called.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,124 [main] INFO    checkOutputSpecs called.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,135 [main] INFO    output format=class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
2015-06-30 00:08:32,140 [main] INFO    Output format class is set to: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
2015-06-30 00:08:32,152 [main] INFO    Output committer is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter
2015-06-30 00:08:32,154 [JobControl] INFO    CustomOutputFormat created.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,156 [JobControl] INFO    Output format class is set to: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
2015-06-30 00:08:32,159 [JobControl] INFO    Output committer is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter
2015-06-30 00:08:32,166 [JobControl] INFO    getOutputFormat called.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,169 [JobControl] INFO    checkOutputSpecs called.
2015-06-30 00:08:32,175 [JobControl] INFO    output format=class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
```

Things that I notice:

- `getOutputFormat` and `getRecordWriter` are never called on `CustomOutputFormat`. Why?
- `prepareToWrite` is never called on MyStoreFunc. What?
- `checkOutputSpecs` *is* called on `CustomOutputFormat`, so it's clear that Pig "knows about" this class and is getting it from `MyStoreFunc`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share the actual code?

Comment: I can't share the original source, but I've mocked up code that's very similar to how the original code is structured and provided example log output.